# Restricting a particular IP in MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos

I am new to `Mac OS X` and I've installed `MAMP`. I would like to restrict a particular IP in MySQL. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use bin address in MySQL configuration:

Refer to this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address.)